# How to handle ASP.NET Application variables in a load-balanced web farm

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing

I am moving a site from a single server to a server farm consisting of three web servers behind a load balancer.  It seems easy enough to handle session management - just make sessions "sticky" at the Load Balancer (we evaluated SQL-based session management but have decided to continue using InProc session management for efficiency).

However, we also use a sizable configuration object that we keep in the Application space (e.g. Application[ObjName]).  Since the config object is loaded from memory, we have no problem until someone makes a change to the configuration.  At that point, the application on the hosting server will have the change and the database will have the change. However, the other two servers won't have the change.  We've debated having a "once a minute" polling rule (e.g. on new sessions), keeping information in the session instead (not very efficient), etc.  All have serious drawbacks.  I am wondering what other people do.  Is it possible to keep the Application space on SQL Server but the Session space inproc?  Any help or insight about how to handle this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application[] is always going to be local memory based, so no matter what you've going to have some code changes to make. So put it somewhere else, like a distributed cache, [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx), [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/), [memcached.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet/) etc. When someone makes a change to the configuration update the cache, when you need to read the settings read from the cache. Propogation/Sync is taken care of by the cache itself.

Comment: Thanks @blowdart.  We checked out AppFabric and NCache but ultimately decided to poll every 10 minutes.  Configuration changes are made so rare once a system is running that we didn't think it worthwhile to add another third-party component.  Still, I liked AppFabric and, if we ever truly need a distributed cache, it is nice to have it in our back pocket.

Answer (score 0):

We currently decided to use NCache as we have got 4 web servers for our web farms.  This third party caching tool can work perfectly with load balancer and is easy to configure(just the Express version of it is free. For Professional and Enterprise version, only Developer Machine is out of charge).  It is also really fast and  stable. You must setup the NChache on each server and set the load balancer to work with all of them. Hope it helps.